# Continuity at a point and open preimage

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be two metric spaces, let $f:X \mapsto Y$ be continuous at a point $x_0$, that is: for any neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ there exists an open set $U$ such that: $x_0 \in U \subset f^{-1}(V)$.

My question is the following: if in particular $V$ is a ball centered at $f(x_0)$, i.e.

$V=\{ g\in Y: d(f(x_0),g)<\epsilon\}$

is it true that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open with respect $d_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is continuous at $0$. But $f^{-1}\left(\left(-1,1\right)\right)=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cup(-1,1)$, which is not an open set.

Comment: Good answer. Please disregard my wrong answer, which I'll try to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If the assumption is that *$f$ is continuous at $x_0$* (i.e., not in the whole $X$), then $f^{-1}(V)$ is NOT NECESSARILY an open subset of $X$.

Example
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational} \\
x & \text{if $x$ is rational}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$, and
$$
f^{-1}\big((-1,1)\big)=(-1,1)\cap \mathbb Q,
$$
which is not an open subset of $\mathbb R$.